# join tables and display result [Laravel 5]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have `groups` table `project_group` pivot table `questions` table

`groups` table:

```
+----+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name   | updated_at          | created_at          |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | GROUP1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|  2 | GROUP2 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+----+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

pivot table `project_group`:

```
+-----+----------+------------+----------+---------+-----------+
| ids | group_id | project_id | admin_id | user_id | user_name |
+-----+----------+------------+----------+---------+-----------+
|   4 |      115 |          1 |        1 |       3 | CLIENT    |
|   5 |      115 |          2 |        1 |       3 | CLIENT    |
+-----+----------+------------+----------+---------+-----------+
```

questions table:

```
+----+----------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+                                                                             
| id | group_id | text          | updated_at          | created_at                                                                                      
+----+----------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |      115 | PRVO PITANJE? | 2015-05-03 14:29:16 | 2015-05-03 14:29:16 |
| 26 |      115 | DRUGO PITANJE? | 2015-05-06 00:44:02 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+----+----------+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

What I want is to display something like this:

### GROUP 1

PRVO PITANJE?

DRUGO PITANJE?

BUT also to check if user 3 logged from pivot table and display that just for that user. I think it should be some JOIN project_group and question table and then to put `where user_id = Atuh::id()`

Any solution? :)

Comment: I've answered below using SQL -- which should be what you do first. I see you have tagged Laravel 5, but I'm not sure why. The SQL is super-simple to write in QueryBuilder. However, if you want to do this with Eloquent models we'd need to show a lot more code. Even then, though, it's just a matter of using Eloquent's relations to model what is in the SQL below.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I am checking it now. I tagged Laravel 5 because I use Eloquent...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your `id` on `groups` ought to align with `group_id` on `project_group`, right? So, I'll assume 'GROUP1' has id of 115 and not 1 as you have it.

Secondly, how do questions relate to projects? You have `group_id` on questions, which seems like it should be a project id, but this isn't certain.

SELECT `text`
FROM `questions`
INNER JOIN `project_group` USING (`group_id`)
INNER JOIN `groups` ON `project_group`.`project_id`=`groups`.`id`
WHERE `groups`.`name`='GROUP1'
AND `project_group`.`user_id`=3;

Again, this will only work if you correct `group_id` to be a foreign key referencing `id` on the `groups` table. In this case, this should do what you want.

Comment: 1. You are right   2. Project and groups are related also group and questions are related, so for example if `user with id 3` open `project with id 1`  he will get `group with id 115`and `questions with id 1 and 26`... I can't use `foreign key` because I use MyIsam

Comment: Well don't confuse the meaning of foreign key with formally creating a foreign key constraint. You have a foreign key because the key you have in one table is the primary key of another.  Because you are using MyISAM you can't have the database enforce data integrity across this FK relationship for you, but it is a foreign key nonetheless.