# Can't access to id property from MySQL table in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Problem is with foreach loop I can take this value: `$gro -> name` but when I try this `$gro -> id` not working just return null. Here is my function:

```
$adminIdCondition = function($q){
     $q->where('project_group.admin_id', Auth::user()->admin_id)
       ->where('project_id', $this->id)
       ->where('user_id',Auth::id())->where('actived',0);
};
$groups = Group::with(['projects' => $adminIdCondition])
     ->whereHas('projects', $adminIdCondition)
     ->get();

$questions = array(); 
foreach($groups as $gro){
     $questions[] = array(
          $gro->name => Question::where('group_id',$gro->id)->lists('text')
     );
}

return $questions;
```

Also If I dump $groups I can find id value...

Comment: How is your database schema setup?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507670/join-tables-and-display-result-laravel-5